# How do I find out roots of quadratic equation in C?

Tags: c, quadratic

I'm pretty new to C and I'm just starting out with some beginner questions. I code I wrote below seems correct however the answer is incorrect. Can any help me figure?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    system("cls");
    int a, b, c;
    float x, y, bac, bbac;
    printf("Enter value of a, b, & c\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    bac = b*b-4*a*c;
    bbac = sqrt(bac);
    
    if (bac<0) {
        printf("The roots are imaginary");
    } else {
        x = (-b+bbac)/2*a;
        y = (-b+bbac)/2*a;
        printf("Roots are %f & %f", x, y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never describe a problem merely as “the answer is incorrect.” Always state what input you gave to the program, what output you observed, and what output you expected or desired instead. Sometimes programs give correct output for some inputs and not others, so, if you do not give an example of input that results in failure, other people might not be able to see what the problem is. Also, if you do not explain what is different between what the program does and what you expect, people might not understand what you think the problem is.

Comment: @JohnKugelman that is what I meant. I didn't read further before commenting. It should test *before* taking the `sqrt`.

Comment: After running the code snippet, as John states in his answer, this is a math issue not a software issue :) expect that you forgot to ``#include <math.h>``

Comment: @Sorenp more like a copy/paste error. Clearly OP knows there should be two roots with (usually) different solutions.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, I agree it looks like copy/paste, the root of all evil - no pun intended.

Comment: Properly parenthesize the divisor. `x = (-b-bbac)/(2*a);` and `y = (-b+bbac)/(2*a);`

Answer (score 3):

You're calculating the same value for `x` and `y`. One of them should have `-b-bbac`.

```
x = (-b+bbac)/(2*a);
y = (-b-bbac)/(2*a);
```